# Editing specific table row content in React

Tags: reactjs, row, edit

I have made this table and added buttons that will allow for editing and deleting specific rows. I have already implemented the functionality for deletion but have no idea where to start for editing specific rows.

Here is the
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5E8x0.png)

I understand that when I press the edit button there should be a component that tracks true or false.. true showing the edit view(textinput in place of where the text content is on the table) and false just showing the text content in the tables. But further from that not sure how to get only textboxes to show only for the specific row the user presses edit on.

Here is my state code:

```
state = {
shoes : [
{
  name:”hello”
  list: [
  {
  {brand: 'klsdnalkd', type: 'da,sbd,ads', company: 'daskjbdas', binding: 'dasjdbas', style: 'dasdjkb', quantity: 1, id: 1},
  { brand: 'dyasidu82', type: 'dasdkasnd', company: 'dasndbamnsbda', quantity: 1, id: 2},
  { brand: 'dalsknda', type: 'dasljndas', company: 'dsaknal', quantity: 5, id: 3}
}]
]
}
```

I understand that I have to use each arrays unique id somehow to reference the edit button but how would I go about doing this with the code I already have for rendering the table?

Here is the component code for rendering the table(Please disregard some of the passed in functions there I was just trying a bunch of things to try and implement this):

```
const TableRender = ({shoes, deleteShoeEvent, editingRowToggle, editRowToggle, showRowEditMode, showRowNormalMode}) => {
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
const shoesList = shoes.map(shoe => {
    return(
        <tbody class="tbody">
            <tr class="tr" /*onMouseOver={() => setShow(!show)} onMouseOut={() => setShow(!show)}*/ key={shoe.id} {...!editingRowToggle ? showRowNormalMode: showRowEditMode}>
                <td class="td"> 
                    {shoe.brand}
                    <td>
                        <Button className="edit-delete-buttons" variant="tertiary" handleClick={editRowToggle} size="xs" >Edit</Button>
                        <Button className="edit-delete-buttons" variant="tertiary" size="xs" handleClick={() => {deleteShoeEvent(shoe.id)}}>Delete</Button>
                    </td>
                </td>
                <td class="td">
                    <div>{shoe.type}</div>
                    <div>{shoe.company}</div>
                    <div>{shoe.author ? shoe.author : null}</div>
                    <div>{shoe.binding ? shoe.binding : null}</div>
                    <div>{shoe.style ? shoe.style : null}</div>
                </td>
                <td class="td">
                    {shoe.quantity}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    )
})
return(
    <Fragment>
        {shoesList}
    </Fragment>
)
}
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

```
Const edit = (editedShoe) => {
 Shoes = shoes.map(shoe => {
    If(shoe.id === id){
          Shoe = {...editedShoe}
    }

    Return shoe
 })
}
```

And with this you do onClick edit(clicked row)...

Comment: Thanks for the response but how would I do it with my updated state structure edited in the post?